# Typo3 11.5 routeEnhancer ignored? configuration incorrect?

Tags: routes, typo3-11.x

I am trying to configure a route enhancer for my extension in Typo3 11.5.

```
    /unterkategorie.html?tx_my_products_subcategory%5Baction%5D=products&tx_my_products_subcategory%5Bcontroller%5D=Subcategory&tx_my_products_subcategory%5Buid%5D=15&cHash=182688e...
```

Configuration looks like:

```
    Products:
      type: Extbase
      extension: MyProducts
      plugin: Subcategory
      limitToPages: [15,16,17,26,27,28]
      routes:
        - routePath: '/{name}'
          _controller: 'Subcategory::products'
          _arguments:
            name: uid
      aspects:
        name:
          type: PersistedAliasMapper
          tableName: tx_myproducts_domain_model_subcategory
          routeFieldName: name
```

I'm already using very similar configurations in similar extensions and everything works fine, but this route enhancers seems to be ignored :-(

Is there anything wrong in the configuration?

How can I check whether Typo3 actually has a look at it?

(Indentation by spaces is ok, cache has been cleared many times, ...)

Thanks for any hint!

Anna

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe there is a problem with an older redirect that changes the path name or some other setting that the routeEnhancer reacts to?

Comment: Thank your very much! I'll have a try with this hypothesis :-)